# Rust macro with dots in token trees

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to create a Rust macro that generates endpoints like `"/api/v2/stats/<token>"`.

I thought it would be cool to make it like [warp path](https://docs.rs/warp/latest/warp/macro.path.html) does it: `warp::path!("sum" / u32 / u32)`.
But in warp, they do not need to support token trees with dots, i.e. expressions, and retrieve their values...

What I got so far is this:

```rust
macro_rules! path {
    () => {};
    ($next:tt $($tail:tt)*) => {{
        println!(stringify!($next));
        path!($($tail)*);
    }};
}

fn main() {
    struct Data {
        event: String,
        token: String,
    }
    let data = Data {
        event: String::from("stats"),
        token: String::from("a1b2c3d4"),
    };
    path!("/api/v2" / data.event / data.token)
}
```

playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=babf87265cc6060fc1695019e30e38bf

This shows what the macro is seeing:

```
"/api/v2"
/
data
.
event
/
data
.
token
```

I know token trees can be reinterpreted as expressions later, so there should be a way to keep tt's in tail, split slashes from "anything else", and get those as expressions to retrieve their values, but I'm not seeing how...

How could I make it return the String `"/api/v2/stats/a1b2c3d4"`?

More examples of inputs and expected outputs:

```rust
struct Conf<'a> {env: &'a str};
let conf = Conf { env: "dev" };
let subsystem = "stats";

path!("/"); // root: "/"
path!("/api/v1" / data.event / "results"); // "/api/v1/stats/results"
path!("/api/v2/errors" / conf.env / subsystem); // "/api/v2/errors/dev/stats"
```

EDIT: I *kinda* did it with expressions, which it not that expressive, more of a workaround, but it works:

```rust
macro_rules! path {
    ($($path:expr),+) => {{
        let mut s = [$($path),+].into_iter().flat_map(|p| [p, "/"]).collect::<String>();
        s.pop();
        s
    }}
}
```

Limitations: it only accepts commas, the path parts have to be &str so I have to manually reference them, and most of all, this could be better represented as a function, but is something to start with:

```rust
let result_url = path!("/api/v2", &data.event, &data.token);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give some more usage examples with input and expected output?

Comment: I've achieved a possible workaround using commas and expressions, but it isn't what I'd like yet...

Comment: You could also require parentheses for non-literals in the macro input: `path!("/api/v2" / (data.event) / (data.token))`

Comment: In fact, you'll need to do something like that, since you'll have to parse `data.event` as an expression, and that can't grammatically be followed by a `/`. This would be required for supporting things like `data.token.to_uppercase()`.

Comment: That's a nice idea, thanks @PeterHall! But I still think there should be a way to interpret them as expressions only at the very last step, like in a [TT muncher](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-incremental-tt-munchers.html)...

Comment: It might just be easier to use a custom struct that implements [`Div<Rhs: Display>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Div.html) to append path elements, similar to Python's [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html#operators).

Comment: The problem is that an arbitrary expression could contain a `/`, so you'd need to disambiguate that if you didn't want to be limited to just chaining field accessors with `.` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tt muncher to achieve this:

```rust
macro_rules! path {
    (@munch / ) => {
        String::from("/")
    };
    (@munch / $part:literal $(/)* ) => {
        format!("/{}", $part)
    };
    (@munch / $part:literal / $($tail:tt)* ) => {
        format!("/{}{}", $part, path!(@munch / $($tail)*))
    };
    (@munch / $($parts:ident).+ $(/)* ) => {
        format!("/{}", & $($parts).+)
    };
    (@munch / $($parts:ident).+ / $($tail:tt)* ) => {
        format!("/{}{}", & $($parts).+, path!(@munch / $($tail)*))
    };
    (/ $($input:tt)*) => {
        path!(@munch / $($input)*)
    };
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c2cf52980ee74f331f34536204779704)

Currently this produces nested `format!` calls. In order to avoid that you'll probably also need to use an accumulator. This kinda stuff interests me so I'm working on a version with an accumulator.

Edit: And here's the accumulator version

```rust
macro_rules! path {
    (/) => {
        String::from("/")
    };
    (/ $($input:tt)*) => {
        path!(@munch { / $($input)* } => ())
    };

    (@munch { / $part:literal $(/)* } => ($($accum:expr),*)) => {
        path!(@done ($( $accum, )* $part))
    };
    (@munch { / $part:literal / $($tail:tt)* } => ($($accum:expr),*)) => {
        path!(@munch { / $($tail)* } => ($( $accum, )* $part ))
    };
    
    (@munch { / $($parts:ident).+ $(/)* } => ($($accum:expr),*)) => {
        path!(@done ($( $accum, )* & $($parts).+ ))
    };
    (@munch { / $($parts:ident).+ / $($tail:tt)* } => ($($accum:expr),*)) => {
        path!(@munch { / $($tail)* } => ($( $accum, )* & $($parts).+ ))
    };

    (@replace_expr $_t:tt => $sub:expr) => { $sub };
    (@done ($($accum:expr),*)) => {
        format!(
            concat!($( path!(@replace_expr ($accum) => "/{}"), )*),
            $( $accum, )*
        )
    };
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=02a67e0c25d147b45d60a1fd18599c4d)

Edit2: per your request, another version which uses two accumulators to support a leading literal

```rust
macro_rules! path {
    (/) => {
        String::from("/")
    };
    (/ $($input:tt)*) => {
        path!(@munch { / $($input)* } -> () : ())
    };
    ($part:literal $(/)*) => {
        String::from($part)
    };
    ($part:literal $($input:tt)*) => {
        path!(@munch { $($input)* } -> ("{}") : ($part))
    };

    (@munch { / $part:literal $(/)* } -> ($($fmt_accum:literal),*) : ($($args_accum:expr),*)) => {
        path!(@done ($( $fmt_accum, )* "/{}") : ($( $args_accum, )* $part))
    };
    (@munch { / $part:literal / $($tail:tt)* } -> ($($fmt_accum:literal),*) : ($($args_accum:expr),*)) => {
        path!(@munch { / $($tail)* } -> ($( $fmt_accum, )* "/{}") : ($( $args_accum, )* $part ))
    };
    
    (@munch { / $($parts:ident).+ $(/)* } -> ($($fmt_accum:literal),*) : ($($args_accum:expr),*)) => {
        path!(@done ($( $fmt_accum, )* "/{}") : ($( $args_accum, )* & $($parts).+ ))
    };
    (@munch { / $($parts:ident).+ / $($tail:tt)* } -> ($($fmt_accum:literal),*) : ($($args_accum:expr),*)) => {
        path!(@munch { / $($tail)* } -> ($( $fmt_accum, )* "/{}") : ($( $args_accum, )* & $($parts).+ ))
    };

    (@done ($($fmt_accum:literal),*) : ($($args_accum:expr),*)) => {
        format!(
            concat!($( $fmt_accum, )*),
            $( $args_accum, )*
        )
    };
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a4b5577821a83c56638e29e7f73b3598)

Comment: Wow, amazing @PitaJ!! The nested `format!` can simply be changed to `format_args!` calls, with a `format!("{}", path!())` at the main level. I just find not that mnemonic to always start with single slashes, but I tried to remove this and couldn't...

Comment: Interesting, you didn't even need to coerce parts into expressions to retrieve their values! TIL it, I wasn't aware you could "assemble" idents with dots and the code would work, very cool!!

Comment: @rsalmei Check out the edit with the accumulator version

Comment: Simply amazing @PitaJ! I have to study it thoroughly, cause I confess I can't really understand it atm... For the cherry on top, is it possible to have `path!("/api...` instead of `path!(/ "api...`?

Comment: Should be possible. Let me try

Comment: Probably harder to follow, but fewer rules so slightly less recursion involved: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=ce2efac8b3983cdf24aafb644de4205e

Comment: @eggyal also only supports types that dereference to `&str`, whereas mine supports anything that impls `Display`.

Comment: WOW, this is awesome @eggyal! I'd also like to study your version thoroughly because I can't seem to grasp it.... Pretty cool!

Comment: @rsalmei: Basically, it's building at the "head" an array `["/api/v2", "/", &*data.event, "/", &*data.token]` by starting with an empty array `[]` and then shifting what's next from the "tail" into it in each recursive macro call.  But @PitaJ is right that my expressions must deref to `str` whereas their approach (invoking the `format!` macro) is more general: have a go at combining the two approaches?

Comment: Rust macros are a language in itself, a huge one actually, and I'm glad to have two macro wizards here!! Thank you PitaJ and eggyal.

Comment: @rsalmei see edit with latest version. If it behaves to your satisfaction, I will add some comments to explain what is happening

Comment: Yes! It's even more than I expected @PitaJ! You've made it support BOTH a leading slash and a literal.... That's really cool, I'm really thankful!

Comment: Oh @PitaJ, a related doubt please: In another part of my code I need to include suffixes to these paths, something like "?err=invalid_key". I'm trying to use the `path!` macro within another macro that calls it with only one part: `concat!("/failure", $suffix)`, but it fails with `no rules expected the token concat!("/failure", "?err=invalid_key")`... Is there something that I could do to make this literal be resolved _first_?

Comment: Might be useful to throw in a link to the [unofficial reference on tt munchers](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/tt-muncher.html).

Comment: Thanks @Jmb, but I did throw this exact link a few hours ago, in the question's comments.

Comment: @rsalmei unfortunately it's just how macros in Rust work, but you can handle it manually as shown [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1ef0dc453a7f83398869d3034c09b350)

Comment: Actually here's a simpler version that supports all kinds of expressions as the final part: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fac82dd9c71439b5140c1e50e0c4753a). It doesn't support trailing slashes, but I figure that's not a huge deal.